# How do I fix Outlook OST Synchronization Error 8004011D

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I cannot send or receive any emails in Outlook because of this error message.  The error may be intermittent and Outlook may say Disconnected or Connected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Close Outlook, Delete the *.OST file in c:\users\%username%\appdata\local\microsoft\outlook, open Outlook and see if the issue is fixed.
2. Close Outlook, open Control Panel, Open Mail, Click profiles, Create a new profile and set it as the default.  Open Outlook and see if the issue is fixed.
3. Repair Office
4. Reinstall Office

**Unlikely:**

Open Chrome (maybe firefox and new edge have the same risk) and see if you have any sketchy extensions.  I had a user where an extension was installed that they did not add (related to email) and removing the extension(s) fixed this error message.  If this happens to you, run a virus scan.  This is the whole reason I am posting this in case it happens to someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Many possible factors may cause issues like this such as network issues or corrupted Outlook profile and datafile. Please check this article and see if could help solve your issue [Outlook Troubleshooting: OST Synchronization Error 8004011D-526-80040115-0](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/37196.outlook-troubleshooting-ost-synchronization-error-8004011d-526-80040115-0.aspx).

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mark my answer as the answer.  Thanks for adding that link though.  My fix was unrelated to anything I found online so that is why I posted this.